# Google Analytics Tracking across subdomain and one specific subdirectory

Tags: google-analytics

I've gone through all the GA documentation and understand pretty well how to track across subdomains. I need to do something slightly different. My sites are moving from subdomains to subdirs onto one subdomain (www). From site1.domain.com to www.domain.com/site1, etc. Previously, there was nothing on www, only the subdomains, which all have their own tracking id, ie. 12345-2, 12345-3, etc. Both sites (old and new) will be live at the same time, so we need to aggregate and track across the subdomains (got that down, w/ all the filters needed) but also track/link only a specific directory on the www to each of the old subdomains. One kink is that while all the sites will map easily from site1.domain.com -> www.domain.com/site1, one special site - online.domain.com will map to www.domain.com/ with no subdir.

I figured I could solve the subdir issue by only placing the code for each property id on the respective subdir pages. I.e. site1=12345-2, and all the pages in /site1 get that code. For the online.domain.com site, the property-id specific code would have to be added to about 20 other subdirs, like /about/, /contact/, etc.  Is this correct or kludgy? And i might even add new profiles that filter for subdir as a backup measure. But the issue I am having is this, I really want to track them as separate sites so that referral, time on site, etc metrics are specific to each subdir (site) and not shared across all the subdomains (which I think what subdomain cross tracking enables.) So I thought the solution was _setCookiePath, but can I use that on one subdomain (www) while cross-tracking and not the other? Because the old site won't have /site1/ as a valid path. Logically, is this something I even can do? Won't setting _setCookiePath on one side defeat the purpose of cross subdomain tracking?

I am confused about the usage of _setCookiePath  when tracking subdirectories. When do you use setCookiePath and when do you just filter the data via subdir with profiles? The documentation says if you use _setCookiePath you need to disable tracking at the root level. What is the issue there? (I don't think this would work for me because I also need to track other top-level dirs like /about/). Also in another rollup account I want to track all the sites with one property id and then use filters to set up unique profiles for each subdir/site, eventually retiring the old method that uses multiple profile IDs. But I want to track my subdirs as separate sites with separate cookie info so that a referral to www.domain.com/site1 is not shared with www.domain.com/site2 - is this impossible with my requirements? More importantly, visits and uniques need to be segmented by subdir. A user that comes to /site1 then goes to /site2 needs to be a new visitor on /site2.

Update: did I totally overthink this? Since users probably wont be moving between old and new sites can I just add the same tracking property id to both sites w/o crossdomain tracking? That would help me consolidate old and new, but I still have the issue of how to track all the new subdir sites as different sites that don't share cookie info.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are moving from a more complex set up to a far simpler one.

If your new domain structure is:

- www.site.com/one
- www.site.com/two
- www.site.com/three
- www.site.com/four

Then the standard default Google Analytics code snippet will work. IE Without cross domain tracking, just select 'single domain' when setting up your new profile.

The only issue i can see is that current your data is stored in different profiles. Using this new setup all data will be stored in one single profile. However using the 'Page' metric you could create advanced segments to separate traffic visiting 'Pages' beginning with '/one' for example. Or you could create multiple filters with Page based filtering to separate the traffic from 'www.site.com/one' from 'www.site.com/two'.